# jQuery: multiselect click event doesn't respond to click

Tags: jquery, select, click, textarea

I have a multiselect box that contains a list of image urls. I am trying to enable a click event on the multiselect box: when a user clicks on a url, it should pass the url to a textarea with the id of "articleFullText". Below is my jquery code, however, it doesn't work and does not cause any error on JS console:

```
$('.multiselect').click(function() {
                    var src = $(this).val();
                    $('#articleFullText').val($('articleFullText').val() + src);
                });
```

**My selectbox html:**

```
<div class="controls">
                            <select name="images" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">

                             <option value="http://localhost/images/1.jpg">http://localhost/images/1.jpg</option>
<option value="http://localhost/images/2.jpg">http://localhost/images/2.jpg</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
```

**textarea code:**

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="articleFullText" id="articleFullText></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mistakes: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/dGa97/1/

A missing # selector:

```
$('.multiselect').click(function () {
    var src = $(this).val() +"blah";
    $('#articleFullText').val($('#articleFullText').val() + src);
});
```

And a missing closing quote on `id="articleFullText"`:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="articleFullText" id="articleFullText"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't use the right event (change).

```
$('.multiselect').on('change', function() {
  $('#articleFullText').append($(this).val())
});
```

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9Ya27/1/

Comment: `Click` works fine. This is an alternative, that avoids some of the issues, but not the solution to the actual problem :),

Answer (score 2):

You are missin the # on the selector:

```
$('#articleFullText').val($('articleFullText').val() + src);
```

change to:

```
$('#articleFullText').val($('#articleFullText').val() + src);
```

And the Id in the textarea has not a closing `""` change it to:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="articleFullText" id="articleFullText"></textarea>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NFqk7/)